# Does Hazelcast fast aggregator or jet uses previously aggregated result

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-jet

We are planning to use of fast aggregator or hzc jet. We have a requirement to aggregate based on an infinite streqm of messgaes. So lets say if i recieve same type of message will it cache the previously aggregated data or it will calculate based on all previous messages of that type for eg lets say we have to aggregate marks of student and key being student id
we have kafka topic where continous meseages are coming contaning student id and marks and some other detail.
Now lets say we recieve 4 message of student 1,

> 1, 90 - output 90
>   2,80 - 170
>   3, 70 - 240
>   4 100- 370

In this case every time we recive message will hazelcast jet caches the last aggregate result or it will aggregate all the messages every time

Comment: have updated the question to be more clear, can you please upvote again.

Answer (score 1):

@Abhishek, you can do both ways. There are aggregate operations that you can run on a subset of data continuously, windowing, or you can use Rolling Aggregate operations that will do the aggregation for each item & carry the previous results.

Please see examples here:

- For Windowed Aggregation: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-jet-code-samples/blob/0.7-maintenance/sliding-windows/src/main/java/TopNStocks.java
- For Rolling Aggreagation: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-jet-code-samples/blob/master/rolling-aggregation/src/main/java/TradingVolume.java